# Best way to extend eclipse Java project wizard?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I am writing an eclipse plug-in and I need to provide a functionality to let the user create a custom project which is **basically a plain old Java project** with my jar as a dependency and my sample class in the source folder.

It should also have my custom nature (this is to tag the project / change its icon so that it stands out visually).

**The user must be able to choose at least the name of the project and its location**, and preferably the Java execution environment because it must be 8+.

My understanding is the way to do this is to create a custom `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point. I have considered following solutions :

1. **Extending `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.JavaProjectWizard`**, to just add my jar, class and custom nature at creation. Problem is this class is "not API" and I should not be extending it.
2. **Create a basic wizard with just project name and location** (and maybe Java environment combo box), **and add Java project settings myself** (java nature, source and output locations...). This is now my preferred option, but I'm wondering how simple it is to do it ? If I just add Java nature, I guess all associated preferences for the project will appear automatically...?
3. Project doesn't really have special behavior, so a an **Example wizard** might do.

What would be the best solution in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention you should not use JavaProjectWizard as this is an internal class and may be changed without notices.

You can use `org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.BasicNewProjectResourceWizard` to create a project. This does not let you change the wizard pages but you can override the `performFinish` to do the additional operations you need.

Adding the Java nature to the project will indeed make the various Java preference pages available.

Comment: There are also the `NewJavaProjectWizardPage` (deprecated), `NewJavaProjectWizardPageOne`,`NewJavaProjectWizardPageTwo` and `JavaCapabilityConfigurationPage` wizard pages that you may embed in your wizard if you see fit.